# Change arrow head of \xrightarrow[]{}

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows

I am using `\xrightarrow{}` in many places in my document. I want to change the tip to look like the one that gets produced by `-latex`.

I am trying to get a similar tip for the `\xrightarrow{}` macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`chemarrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemarrow) package provides extensible arrows with such heads, for example

```
\autorightarrow{above}{below}
```

[image]

amsmath uses `\rightarrow` for the extensible right arrow. You could easily use `\chemarrow` instead, changing also the fixed arrow for consistency:

```
\usepackage{chemarrow}
\let\rightarrow\chemarrow
...
$\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}$
```

Or patch just the amsmath extensible arrow command(s), keeping the original `\rightarrow`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\rightarrowfill@}{%
  \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\chemarrow}
\makeatother
```

[image]