# Arrow in the homomorphism

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

[image]

In the first homomorphism, the latex code for the arrow is either `\rightarrow` or `\to` or `\longrightarrow`.

I like the arrow style in the second homomorphism. Can someone show me the latex code for this arrow?

Thanks all!

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7174/133968

Comment: The first is just a standard `\to` the other is made using the `xy` package. Though, I would recommend using `tikz-cd` instead.

Comment: @daleif Can you help me to write latex code for that arrow? Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not a `do this for me` site. Both the `tikz-cd` and `xy` packages have manuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the arrow style only in the second homomorphism using `xy` package. It possible to use out `\xymatrix`, `\rightarrow` or `\to` or `\longrightarrow`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}

\usepackage[all]{xy}


\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
(M.\mathbb{F}_p) \ar[r]  &(\mathbb{F}_p \otimes_A \mathscr{R})
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Hoang You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\myto}{\tikz[baseline] \draw[-{>[length=5pt, width=3.5pt]}] (0pt,0pt) (21pt,0pt) (3pt,2.5pt) -- (18pt,2.5pt);}
\begin{document}
\(a \to b \myto c\)
\end{document}
```

[image: "a" "b" and "c" with arrows]

Comment: Thank you very much!